# Socket information from Linux-Java thread dump

Tags: java, linux, sockets, thread-dump

While analyzing a performance issue, I took continuous thread dumps for every 5 secs, and analyzed using samurai thread dump analyzer. Noticed that, many threads are in runnable state with below stack dump continuously on all the occurrences. But I couldn't find to which host they are communicating. I tried using the commands `ss -t -a`, `watch ss -tp` and `netstat -A inet -p`, but couldn't relate their results with the thread. Any idea? Thanks in advance.

```
Thread dump 2/5 "TP-Processor125"   prio=5 tid=0x25756 nid=0x649c RUNNABLE (JNI Native Code) - stats: cpu=828 blk=-1 wait=-1      java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE      
     at java.net.SocketInputStream.socketRead0(Native Method)      
     at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:152)      
     at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:122)      
     at java.io.BufferedInputStream.fill(BufferedInputStream.java:235)      
     at java.io.BufferedInputStream.read1(BufferedInputStream.java:275)      
     at java.io.BufferedInputStream.read(BufferedInputStream.java:334)      
     at org.apache.jk.common.ChannelSocket.read(ChannelSocket.java:628)
     at org.apache.jk.common.ChannelSocket.receive(ChannelSocket.java:566)
     at org.apache.jk.common.ChannelSocket.processConnection(ChannelSocket.java:693)
     at org.apache.jk.common.ChannelSocket$SocketConnection.runIt(ChannelSocket.java:898)
     at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPool$ControlRunnable.run(ThreadPool.java:690)
     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)      Locked synchronizers: count = 0
```

Comment: Is this for a server or a client? E.g. server socket or a client socket?

Comment: Sorry I don't have that info. All i have is only thread dump taken from the server. It interacts with many interfaces including DB, Webserver ... etc.It says 'SocketInputStream.read'. Could it be server socket ?

Comment: How big is the dump? Can you perhaps upload to Github or some other share?

Comment: What i provided is thread dump only. It is nothing but the stack trace of what the thread is doing by the time the dump is taken.

Answer (score 3):

The `nid` is actually the process/thread ID of the underlying OS (at least for Linux), albeit in hex notation. Convert to decimal pid and use

```
lsof -p pid |grep -Ei 'tcp|socket'
```

to learn more about the socket connections used. It may turn out though, that all sockets are opened by the main thread, in which case the sub-threads only inherit several (many) so it may be difficult to see which thread it connected where.

If `lsof` does not show the thread of the main process (seems it indeed does not) you may have to resolve to looking into `/proc/<pid>/fd`.

Comment: Did this, but not getting the result. Not sure lsof accepts only the process id as opposed to thread id. Also, when i convert hex to decimal, and issue 'ps -eLf | grep 25781' to get the thread detail, not getting any result. Here 25781 is the decimal value for Hex nid(0x64b5).

Answer (score 2):

tid is the Java level thread id and nid is the native thread id. What nid actually refers to on different OS'es, is [somewhat confusing](https://gist.github.com/rednaxelafx/843622). What I would recommend is connecting to your application using a tool such as Visual VM and noting down the PID of the application. Once you have the PID, try the command below:

```
sudo netstat -nlpt
```

This should give you something like below (with remote/local address and PID and program name):

```
Active Internet connections (only servers)
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State       PID/Program name
tcp        0      0 127.0.1.1:53            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1144/dnsmasq    
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:631           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      661/cupsd       
tcp6       0      0 ::1:631                 :::*                    LISTEN      661/cupsd
```

That should tell you which connections are open from your Java program.

Comment: Thank you MajoJojo. But this approach again talks at pid level. What I want to know is at the thread level. Pid has many threads, and thread dump shows what each thread is doing. In unix, ps -eLf commands lists the threads along with process. If we know the process id, we can run 'ps -eLf | grep pid' to know the list of threads. In my thread dump, many threads are reading data from socket, but I couldn't identify what that socket is. Hope I am clear on my question.

Answer (score 0):

From comments and replies to similar questions [Find thread id that open socket for net](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59777155/find-thread-id-that-open-socket-for-net) , [How to view thread id of a process which has opened a socket connection?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6044136/how-to-view-thread-id-of-a-process-which-has-opened-a-socket-connection) , it seems there is no tracking, from the operating system, of the thread that is using a specific opened socket. So it appears to be very difficult to obtain the information you requested.

In the https://stackoverflow.com/a/50273809/1996150 reply there is a suggested (complex) method that requires to log the system calls with strace from the start of the process, and finally debug with gdb the process to find the thread.