# Find thread id that open socket for net

Tags: c, linux, sockets

I want with c linux find out pid(process id) tid(thread id) and socket id that have open socket .

For example pid X has 3 threads A,B,C , but only thread B has socket for Ip Z and fd of this socket is W,

I want to find out X,B,Z,W.

I tried to read the file`/proc/net/tcp` but cant find pid/tid/socket id .

What is the simple way ?running all over /proc and search in each `/proc/pid/task/tid/net` 
(in tcp/udp) whichh one has no empty file?and then how do I get the socket id(the fd of the socket)?

Or maybe running on all over  `proc/pid/task/fd` and check which fd point to socket? (How do I know which Ip this socket bind?)

Or maybe I can get all I need from `/proc/net/tcp`

Comment: I'd be surprised if the operating system knew the thread ID. It certainly doesn't care. Why do you?

Comment: File descriptors (like sockets) in unix are per-process, not per-thread.

Comment: Ok, so how can I get pid and fd of all sockets?